# Spring batch or Spring boot async method execution?

Tags: spring, asynchronous, spring-boot, spring-batch

I have a situation where the data is to be read from 4 different web services, process it and then store the results in a database table. Also send a notification after this task is complete. The trigger for this process is through a web service call.
Should I write my job as a spring batch job or write the whole read/process code as an async method (using @Async) which is called from the Rest Controller?

Kindly suggest

Comment: You need a spring batch if the 4 service is triggered as a scheduled job. Rest Controllers needs to be used if the 4 service calls are triggered by a user of your application.

Comment: The answer should be obvious depending on your Use Case

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my opinion the your choice should be @Async, because Spring Batch was designed for large data processing and it isn't thought to processing on demand, typically you create a your batch and then launch the batch with a schedule. The benefit of this kind of architetture will be the reliability of your job that colud restarted in case of fail and so on. In your case you have a data integration problem and I can suggest to see at Spring Integration. You could have a Spring Integration pipeline that you start through a rest call.

I hope that this can help you

Answer (score 0):

If there are large amounts of services should be executed, `spring-batch` would be the choice. Otherwise, I guess there is no need to import `spring-batch`.

In my opinion, `@Async` annotation is the easier way.

If both methods can work, of course simpler the better.

At the end, if there will be more and more `service` not only 4, `spring-batch` would be the better solution, cause `spring-batch` are professional in this.