# Spring boot send async tasks

Tags: java, spring-boot, asynchronous, spring-rest

I need to send the email/sms/events as a background async task inside spring boot rest.

My REST controller

```
@RestController
public class UserController {

    @PostMapping(value = "/register")
    public ResponseEntity<Object> registerUser(@RequestBody UserRequest userRequest){
       // I will create the user

        // I need to make the asyn call to background job to send email/sms/events
        sendEvents(userId, type) // this shouldn't block the response.

        // need to send immediate response
        Response x = new Response();
        x.setCode("success");
        x.setMessage("success message");
        return new ResponseEntity<>(x, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

How can I make sendEvents **without blocking the response** (no need to get the return **just a background task**) ?

sendEvents- call the sms/email third part api or send events to kafka topic.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like a perfect use case for [the Spring @Async annotation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/annotation/Async.html).

```
@Async
public void sendEvents() {
   // this method is executed asynchronously, client code isn't blocked
}
```

**Important**: `@Async` works only on the public methods and can't be called from inside of a single class. If you put the `sendEvents()` method in the `UserController` class it will be executed synchronously (because the proxy mechanism is bypassed). Create a separate class to extract the asynchronous operation.

In order to enable the async processing in your Spring Boot application, you have to mark your main class with appropriate annotation.

```
@EnableAsync
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication application = new SpringApplication(Application.class);
        application.run(args);
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you can also place the `@EnableAsync` annotation on any `@Configuration` class. The result will be the same.

Comment: Thanks, I am confused with spring batch and integration vs @Async ? are they same usecase or different ?

Comment: This topis answers your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36675656/spring-batch-or-spring-boot-async-method-execution
In your case, @Async seems sufficient.